# Unable to get all ids when dragging multiple ids

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to get multiple dragged ids when i dropped to the certain div.

`$(ui.draggable).attr('id');` only gets 1st id.

Not working:

```
var m_ids = [];
$.each($(ui.draggable), function(i,e) {
    m_ids.push(e.id);  // not getting multiple ids
    alert(m_ids);
});
```

Drag

```
<ul id="demo" > 
     <li id="1" ></li>
     <li id="2" ></li>
     <li id="3" ></li>
</ul>

<div class="drop"> drop here!! </div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(".drop").droppable({ 
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var m_id = $(ui.draggable).attr('id');// only gets 1st id
        var m_ids = [];
        $.each($(ui.draggable), function(i,e) {
             m_ids.push(e.id);  // not getting multiple ids
             alert(m_ids);
        });
    }       
});
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try:

```
var m_ids = [];

$.each($(ui.draggable), function(i,e) {
   m_ids.push(e.id);  // getting all id's of matched elements in $(ui.draggable) selector
});

console.log(m_ids);
```

If there's only one element, `$(ui.draggable)` probably only contains one element, and the other elements could be children, check the console with `console.log($(ui.draggable))`.

Comment: ({selector:"", context:#1=({}), 0:#1#, length:1}) prints for console.log($(ui.draggable)) . Gives length 1 when i have dragged 3 elements. Please help how to fix it.

Comment: Try setting up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), it makes it a lot easier for us to see what it is you are doing, and try to figure out the problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/akkiys/Hkfh2/4/    i have updated. Please reply ASAP thanks a lot